# Transparent SSH Multi-Hop - Access to network without using shell (Shared connection)

Tags: windows, linux, networking, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I have a quick question.  Apologies if this has been posted already, but I have searched and can't seem to find what I am looking for.

I have a ***localhost*** , ***Host 1*** and ***Host 2***.

The ***Host 2*** machine has access to a specific network, but will only accept connections from ***Host 1***, and ***Host 1*** will only accept connections from ***localhost***.  This is a basic SSH multi-hop, I know how to do this part; using Putty.

What I wish to do however is share this SSH connection with my NIC.  This way I can use local administration tools against the ***Host 2*** network and also access specific machines on the network.

Using Putty, I created a proxy using ***localhost*** using port **1024**, which I could then configure with Firefox using the same settings.  I could then view the apache2 default website, proving I had access to that machine.  The problem I am having is being able to do this on my Network Card, as if I was sharing that machines connection.

Is this possible?

Localhost = Windows & Linux\n
Host 1 = Linux\n
Host 2 = Linux\n

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to do SSH port forwarding (as you seem to mention you know how to do) then set up the system-wide proxy settings to point to "localhost" and the port that you forward through. This is effectively tunneling all your traffic through from Host 1 to Host 2.

This guide might help: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/security/use-putty-as-a-secure-proxy-on-windows/421

Comment: I have set up my SSH with port forwarding this time, doing the following:  

ssh username@host1 - L 4444:host1:9090  

Once connected to the first host, typed the following:  

ssh -D 9090 username@host2  

This then connects me to Host 2.  I then configure a system wide proxy on Socks as LocalHost:4444  

Surely this should work? It doesnt seem to be.  

I have also tried replacing the system wide proxy with the tool tsocks, though that has yielded me no results either =/  
Apologies for the poor formatting, text seems to be coming up as one block of writing..

Answer (score 0):

Seems this has worked well for me.

http://dev.squarecows.com/2012/03/06/using-ssh-as-a-reverse-tunnel/

Comment: That link is dead